# Is it possible to immediately save any streaming video (without having to download it) once it's fully buffered?

Tags: streaming, youtube

I do notice that it seems to save the entire video buffer for YouTube videos to my hard drive (I used resource manager to find out where): in the cache folder on Chrome

But what about videos other than YouTube ones? E.g. http://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/episodes/bears-of-the-last-frontier/full-episode-hour-one-city-of-bears/6540/

Comment: Cannot be completely clear what you are asking please elaborate a bit more. Do you want to download or only buffer it faster?

Comment: Oh - I want to download it faster (as in, if I watch it and find that it's worth it - I want to be able to download it). I know how to do it for YouTube now, but this doesn't seem to be an option for the pbs site above

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options from what I understand you require.

Internet Download Manager(IDM) downloads directly even you have seen the whole video (a video that is completely buffered), it does not start from first.

A second more appropriate option is Flash video accelerator that comes with Installing Download Accelerator Plus(DAP).

But The only reason I prefer IDM over DAP is the reason that there are no Ads in IDM, However DAP outpeforms due to the video accelerator and also downloads it. It even works for non Flash Videos for download!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer and currently using [videocacheview](http://www.dominantwire.com/2012/11/how-to-download-videos-in-1-click-after.html). You can reteive the buffered files for any website like metacafe, vimeo, youtube etc.

Internet download manager (IDM) and other youtube downloaders suffer from one common flaw that once you have seen the whole video and decide to download it. The downloading starts from the top. Which i find irritating especially when the video is big.

Moreover in videocacheview the video quality is exactly the same as you watched.

Get it [here](http://www.dominantwire.com/2012/11/how-to-download-videos-in-1-click-after.html)